# Regarded / Regarded as

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

Which sentence is better one ?

> Harvard's MBA programme is regarded as the finest in the country.

Or

> Harvard's MBA programme is regarded the finest in the country.

Just like like the use of *As* with *consider* / *considered* is diminishing and its all right to use consider  without as, Can we omit *as* in the above sentence ? Is it grammatically correct ? I am not able to figure the difference in above given sentence but in the below given sentence its clearly wrong to use regard without as :

He regarded her as his sister.

Please don't suggest anything else like replacing *regarded* with *considered* as I don't have that privilege .Its a exam question , considering just those two sentences suggest which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ***regarded*** with ***as*** which has meaning of to consider or have an opinion about something or someone.

For example:

*Her parents always regarded her as the smartest of their children.*